# Spark SQL has no out-of-the-box support to render timestamps in ISO 8601 format w/ timezone specified (T or F ?)

Tags: apache-spark, time, apache-spark-sql, utc

I am hoping  the conclusion that I stated in the title of this  post is not correct. I actually have  found  a round-about way to render timestamps in Java  [DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT).  But my way is very clunky, and I am hoping there is some out-of-the-box way in Spark SQL to do this that I simply have not found yet.

Here is my cumbersome way to do this (from spark-shell):

```
scala> val df = List("1970-01-01 00:00:00.0").toDF("timestr").
     |         withColumn("ts", col("timestr").cast("timestamp")).
     |         withColumn("startOfEpochISO8601", expr("concat(replace(ts, ' ', 'T'), 'Z')"))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [timestr: string, ts: timestamp ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show(false)
+---------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|timestr              |ts                 |startOfEpochISO8601 |
+---------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|1970-01-01 00:00:00.0|1970-01-01 00:00:00|1970-01-01T00:00:00Z|
+---------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

Now, I think there are ways to render timestamps in iso 8601 format if we are outputting to csv or  json.   But I'd like to frame this question in terms of how one would do this if one were writing to some custom output format (without writing to json or csv first to take advantage of existing is0 8601 formatting support, then reading that and  re-writing to the custom format).  The only way i can think of is what I showed above.

Please let me know if you have something better !

UPDATE:

I accepted @Gelerion's answer because it put me on the right track, but I am adding my own answer because there is also the non-obvious requirement that  spark.sql.session.timeZone  be set to UTC or GMT in order for the output to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you right:

```
val timestamped = List("1970-01-01 00:00:00.0").toDF("timestr")
timestamped.select(date_format($"timestr", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z'")).show()

+-------------------------------------------------+
|date_format(timestr, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z')|
+-------------------------------------------------+
|1970-01-01T00:00:00.00Z                          |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: much better than the frankenstein block of code i originally had !     In my original question  I neglected to ask for advice on how to parse the inputs using a pattern such as you provided.  I am going to play around with to_timestamp and try to get that to work for ISO 8601 inputs

Comment: Note that there is a subtle difference in date patterns between SimpleDateFormat (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and DateTimeFormatter (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and Spark works with the former.

Answer (score 1):

I accepted @Gelerion's answer because it put me on the right track, but I am posting this  answer as a supplement because there is also the non-obvious requirement that  spark.sql.session.timeZone  be set to UTC or GMT in order for the output to be correct.

The snippet below relativizes the time 1970-01-01T00:00:00 in a time zone 1 hour behind UTC to the correct UTC value, which is exactly the start of the Unix epoch.This works correctly:

```
  spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "GMT")
  List("1970-01-01T00:00:00-01:00").toDF("timestr").
          withColumn("ts", col("timestr").cast("timestamp")).
          withColumn("tsAsInt", col("ts").cast("integer")).
          withColumn("asUtc", date_format($"ts", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")).
          show(false)
// RESULT:
// +-------------------------+-------------------+-------+--------------------+
// |timestr                  |ts                 |tsAsInt|asUtc               |
// +-------------------------+-------------------+-------+--------------------+
// |1970-01-01T00:00:00-01:00|1970-01-01 01:00:00|3600   |1970-01-01T01:00:00Z|
// +-------------------------+-------------------+-------+--------------------+
```

This shows that if you fail to set spark.sql.session.timeZone to GMT or UTC you will not 
get the correct (relativized to UTC) answer:

```
  spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "PST")
  List("1970-01-01T00:00:00-01:00").toDF("timestr").
          withColumn("ts", col("timestr").cast("timestamp")).
          withColumn("tsAsInt", col("ts").cast("integer")).
          withColumn("asUtc", date_format($"ts", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")).
          show(false)
// RESULT:
// +-------------------------+-------------------+-------+----------------------+
// |timestr                  |ts                 |tsAsInt|asUtc                 |
// +-------------------------+-------------------+-------+----------------------+
// |1970-01-01T00:00:00-01:00|1969-12-31 17:00:00|3600   |1969-12-31T17:00:00-08|
// +-------------------------+-------------------+-------+----------------------+
```